# D&F's Universal Property of Tensor Products - Unnecessary Condition?

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, proof-explanation, tensor-products

In pg 366 of D&F, we having the Corollary 11 after proving Universal Property of $M \otimes _RN$. 
[image]
[image]
I don't understand why can't we argue as we did with Universal Property of Free Groups for Corollary 11; so *condition (i) is unnecssary*?

---

**Proof of Corollary 11:**
From Universal Property of $(i,M \otimes_R N)$ exist $f: M \otimes_R N \rightarrow D$ with $i' = f \circ i $. By Universal Property of $(i',D)$, exists $g:  D \rightarrow M \otimes _R N$ such that $ i = g \circ i' $.

Note then that $f \circ g: D \rightarrow D$ is a homomorphism which satisfies $f \circ (g \circ i') = f \circ i = i' $. So applying Universal Property of $(i', D)$ again wrt $D$,  $f \circ g$ must be identity. Similarly, $g \circ f $ is also identity. So $f$ is an isomoprhism.

---

**Was (i) even necessary in Corollary 11? What is wrong with my proof?**

Comment: If you drop (i), then you need "factors uniquely" instead of "factors" in (ii). Do you see where you used the uniqueness?

Comment: Ah yes, thanks a lot, that is where I can state it equals the identity.